# Code require to connect custom button with metafield using shopify

Tags: shopify, themes, customization, liquid

I have created a button under dynamic buy now button. I need to link that button with custom metafield so user can automatically download pdf by clicking on that button. I am using shopify platform to make store.
Is there any way to do soo i am looking forward to your kind response
Regards

I tried to do it but it doesn't work with me